# C++ container of iterators and circular references

Tags: c++, iterator, containers

I'd like to create two containers that contain iterators to each other. I'd like to do this hopefully without introducing any intermediate/indirect types. Is this possible or do iterator types depending on knowing the size of the container's data type?

Here is some sample code that I'd like to get compiling:

```
#include <map>
#include <deque>
#include <string>

class mapvalue_t
{
  public:
    std::deque< std::map<std::string,mapvalue_t>::iterator  >::iterator i;
};

typedef std::map<std::string,mapvalue_t> maptype_t;
typedef std::deque< maptype_t::iterator > queuetype_t;

int main(void)
{
  maptype_t m;
  queuetype_t q;
}
```

Never mind, it compiles now. I had a queue there, rather than my intended deque :)

Comment: I am not sure editing your question to no-longer-be a question is a good practice.

Answer (score 2):

This works if you use a `deque` instead of a `queue`.   `Queue` is not a container, but a facade so it does not support the `::iterator` call.

From [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/queue/):

> queues are implemented as containers adaptors, which are classes that use an encapsulated  object of a specific container class as its underlying container, providing a specific set of member functions to access it elements. Elements are pushed into the "back" of the specific container and popped from its "front".

Answer (score 1):

You should be very careful about storing iterators.  Modifying the collection can easily invalidate all iterators.  You would be far better storing an id or a (managed) pointer.

Comment: Indeed.  Your stored list of iterators will invalidate every time the map is modified in any way.  You should store key values to the mapping.

Comment: Not quite true. For map and list, inserting and deleting elements does not invalidate any iterators (except of course for the one being deleted).

My question should have a list and not a deque in it, but I don't know if I should bother updating the question yet again.

Comment: If we rely on specific implementations.  I don't think this is guaranteed by the standard.